# Progress bar is not displaying

Tags: powershell

Write-Progress will not display the progress bar if the command in the loop body completes too quick.

```
function process-item($item)
{
   // do something
}

$items = 0..100
$cnt = $items.Count
for($i = 0; $i -lt $cnt; ++$i)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Item #$i" -PercentComplete ($i/$cnt*100) -Status "Processing"
    process-item $items[$i]
}
```

The above code is too fast and the progress bar will not be displayed; well it probably does show up and then closes but is is so fast that I do not see it.

Using sleep command helps but I do not want to use sleep command just so that the progress bar is visible.

Is there a way to instruct PS to keep the progress bar until explicitly closed or  is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

It won't close it if there are other commands running afterwards.

Try adding a sleep after your for, or you could use

```
Read-Host 'Press Enter to Continue'
```

Once all the processes are complete it will close, or you can close it prematurely during your runtime by using

```
Write-Progress -Activity 'xyz' -Completed
```

Comment: Thank you! sleep after the loop works but any other cmdlet won't do it. I could just add sleep after the loop.